# How to convert a number to two decimal places if it is double?

Tags: java, decimal, decimalformat

I am trying to convert a number to two decimal places using Java. Below is what I have tried and it works fine on couple of inputs -

```
double number = 20.3794;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String formattedNumber = df.format(number);
System.out.println(formattedNumber); //output 20.38
```

Below are my scenarios -

- But for this number `20`, output I get back as `20.00`. In this case, I don't need `.00` at the end, it should print out as `20` only.
- Similarly for this number `0.019` it prints out `.02` so for this I need to have `0` infront of `.` so `0.02` should get printed out.

Is this  possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you appear to have exchanged `#` and `0`: `0` is for when you wan to force a zero and `#` is for when the digit is optional.

The pattern `"0.##"` does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `string format` instead with some logic

**sample:**

```
    double s = 20;
    double s2 = 0.019;
    String result1 = String.format("%.2f", s);
    String result2 = String.format("%.2f", s2);

    System.out.println((result1.contains(".00")) ? (int)s : result1);
    System.out.println((result2.contains(".00")) ? (int)s : result2);
```

**result:**

```
20
0.02
```

Answer (score 2):

- To get the 0 in front of a number less than 1, change `"#"` to `"0"`
- To change the whole number printing out to two decimal places, change the two `"0"` in the decimal places to be `"#"` so it only prints them if there are numbers other than 0 in those places.

Basically the problem is that your `"#"` and `"0"` are reversed. Change the pattern to `"0.##"` instead of `"#.00"`. The `#` indicates that a number should only be shown there if it is not 0 (zero shows as absent). The `0` indicates that there will always be a number in that place and it will be 0 if need be. Take a look at [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Here are some examples:

```
double number1 = 20.3794, number2 = 20, number3 = 0.018, number4 = 20.1;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.##");
System.out.println(df.format(number1)); // 20.38
System.out.println(df.format(number2)); // 20
System.out.println(df.format(number3)); // 0.02
System.out.println(df.format(number4)); // 20.1
```

Answer (score 0):

- **For the 1st case:** check `if (number % 1 == 0)` to see if your double is a whole. In case it was, you can cast it to an integer.
- **For the 2nd case:** Try replacing `new DecimalFormat("#.00");` with `new DecimalFormat("0.00");`

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",20.3794)); will print 20.38